# Can I reset column in backlog layout in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I'm using the TFS 2017 (Update 1) and I have just added a new custom field to an existing project.
Now  I would like to know if there is a way to set the backlog layout with the default columns that I have selected for all users ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the new custom field on backlog?

Answer (score 1):

If you export the processconfiguration.xml file and go to the PortfolioBacklogs element, each backlog has a list of columns.  You can add your column there and reimport the processconfiguration.xml.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration